# How to make hyperlink from author name in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a total newbie to Wordpress and having a hard time figuring things out.

I'm using plugin called "WP-Pro-Quiz", a quiz plugin, and within the plugin there's an option to show "Leaderboard" of all users who completed the quiz. In the leaderboard on the frontend, there's user id, time, points and user's Display Name, etc for each user..
What I want to achieve is to make Display name clickable (and then to go to author's profile once clicked). That is, to connect Display Name with author profile who took the quiz, to create hyperlink from Display Name.

This is from controller WpProQuiz_Controller_Toplist.php :

```
 <?php

class WpProQuiz_Controller_Toplist extends WpProQuiz_Controller_Controller
{
    public function route()
    {

        $quizId = $_GET['id'];
        $action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : 'show';

        switch ($action) {
            default:
                $this->showAdminToplist($quizId);
                break;
        }
    }

    private function showAdminToplist($quizId)
    {
        if (!current_user_can('wpProQuiz_toplist_edit')) {
            wp_die(__('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.'));
        }

        $view = new WpProQuiz_View_AdminToplist();
        $quizMapper = new WpProQuiz_Model_QuizMapper();

        $quiz = $quizMapper->fetch($quizId);

        $view->quiz = $quiz;
        $view->show();
    }

    public function getAddToplist(WpProQuiz_Model_Quiz $quiz)
    {
        $userId = get_current_user_id();

        if (!$quiz->isToplistActivated()) {
            return null;
        }

        $data = array(
            'userId' => $userId,
            'token' => wp_create_nonce('wpProQuiz_toplist'),
            'canAdd' => $this->preCheck($quiz->getToplistDataAddPermissions(), $userId),
        );

        if ($quiz->isToplistDataCaptcha() && $userId == 0) {
            $captcha = WpProQuiz_Helper_Captcha::getInstance();

            if ($captcha->isSupported()) {
                $data['captcha']['img'] = WPPROQUIZ_CAPTCHA_URL . '/' . $captcha->createImage();
                $data['captcha']['code'] = $captcha->getPrefix();
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }

    private function handleAddInToplist(WpProQuiz_Model_Quiz $quiz)
    {
        if (!wp_verify_nonce($this->_post['token'], 'wpProQuiz_toplist')) {
            return array('text' => __('An error has occurred.', 'wp-pro-quiz'), 'clear' => true);
        }

        if (!isset($this->_post['points']) || !isset($this->_post['totalPoints'])) {
            return array('text' => __('An error has occurred.', 'wp-pro-quiz'), 'clear' => true);
        }

        $quizId = $quiz->getId();
        $userId = get_current_user_id();
        $points = (int)$this->_post['points'];
        $totalPoints = (int)$this->_post['totalPoints'];
        $name = !empty($this->_post['name']) ? trim($this->_post['name']) : '';
        $email = !empty($this->_post['email']) ? trim($this->_post['email']) : '';
        $ip = filter_var($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
        $captchaAnswer = !empty($this->_post['captcha']) ? trim($this->_post['captcha']) : '';
        $prefix = !empty($this->_post['prefix']) ? trim($this->_post['prefix']) : '';

        $quizMapper = new WpProQuiz_Model_QuizMapper();
        $toplistMapper = new WpProQuiz_Model_ToplistMapper();

        if ($quiz == null || $quiz->getId() == 0 || !$quiz->isToplistActivated()) {
            return array('text' => __('An error has occurred.', 'wp-pro-quiz'), 'clear' => true);
        }

        if (!$this->preCheck($quiz->getToplistDataAddPermissions(), $userId)) {
            return array('text' => __('An error has occurred.', 'wp-pro-quiz'), 'clear' => true);
        }

        $numPoints = $quizMapper->sumQuestionPoints($quizId);

        if ($totalPoints > $numPoints || $points > $numPoints) {
            return array('text' => __('An error has occurred.', 'wp-pro-quiz'), 'clear' => true);
        }

        $clearTime = null;

        if ($quiz->isToplistDataAddMultiple()) {
            $clearTime = $quiz->getToplistDataAddBlock() * 60;
        }

        if ($userId > 0) {
            if ($toplistMapper->countUser($quizId, $userId, $clearTime)) {
                return array('text' => __('You can not enter again.', 'wp-pro-quiz'), 'clear' => true);
            }

            $user = wp_get_current_user();
            $email = $user->user_email;
            $name = $user->display_name;

        } else {
            if ($toplistMapper->countFree($quizId, $name, $email, $ip, $clearTime)) {
                return array('text' => __('You can not enter again.', 'wp-pro-quiz'), 'clear' => true);
            }

            if (empty($name) || empty($email) || filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                return array('text' => __('No name or e-mail entered.', 'wp-pro-quiz'), 'clear' => false);
            }

            if (strlen($name) > 15) {
                return array('text' => __('Your name can not exceed 15 characters.', 'wp-pro-quiz'), 'clear' => false);
            }

            if ($quiz->isToplistDataCaptcha()) {
                $captcha = WpProQuiz_Helper_Captcha::getInstance();

                if ($captcha->isSupported()) {
                    if (!$captcha->check($prefix, $captchaAnswer)) {
                        return array('text' => __('You entered wrong captcha code.', 'wp-pro-quiz'), 'clear' => false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $toplist = new WpProQuiz_Model_Toplist();
        $toplist->setQuizId($quizId)
            ->setUserId($userId)
            ->setDate(time())
            ->setName($name)
            ->setEmail($email)
            ->setPoints($points)
            ->setResult(round($points / $totalPoints * 100, 2))
            ->setIp($ip);

        $toplistMapper->save($toplist);

        return true;
    }

    private function preCheck($type, $userId)
    {
        switch ($type) {
            case WpProQuiz_Model_Quiz::QUIZ_TOPLIST_TYPE_ALL:
                return true;
            case WpProQuiz_Model_Quiz::QUIZ_TOPLIST_TYPE_ONLY_ANONYM:
                return $userId == 0;
            case WpProQuiz_Model_Quiz::QUIZ_TOPLIST_TYPE_ONLY_USER:
                return $userId > 0;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static function ajaxAdminToplist($data)
    {
        if (!current_user_can('wpProQuiz_toplist_edit')) {
            return json_encode(array());
        }

        $toplistMapper = new WpProQuiz_Model_ToplistMapper();

        $j = array('data' => array());
        $limit = (int)$data['limit'];
        $start = $limit * ($data['page'] - 1);
        $isNav = isset($data['nav']);
        $quizId = $data['quizId'];

        if (isset($data['a'])) {
            switch ($data['a']) {
                case 'deleteAll':
                    $toplistMapper->delete($quizId);
                    break;
                case 'delete':
                    if (!empty($data['toplistIds'])) {
                        $toplistMapper->delete($quizId, $data['toplistIds']);
                    }
                    break;
            }

            $start = 0;
            $isNav = true;
        }

        $toplist = $toplistMapper->fetch($quizId, $limit, $data['sort'], $start);

        foreach ($toplist as $tp) {
            $j['data'][] = array(
                'id' => $tp->getToplistId(),
                'name' => $tp->getName(),
                'email' => $tp->getEmail(),
                'type' => $tp->getUserId() ? 'R' : 'UR',
                'date' => WpProQuiz_Helper_Until::convertTime($tp->getDate(),
                    get_option('wpProQuiz_toplistDataFormat', 'Y/m/d g:i A')),
                'points' => $tp->getPoints(),
                'result' => $tp->getResult()
            );
        }

        if ($isNav) {

            $count = $toplistMapper->count($quizId);
            $pages = ceil($count / $limit);
            $j['nav'] = array(
                'count' => $count,
                'pages' => $pages ? $pages : 1
            );
        }

        return json_encode($j);
    }

    public static function ajaxAddInToplist($data)
    {
        // workaround ...
        $_POST = $_POST['data'];

        $ctn = new WpProQuiz_Controller_Toplist();

        $quizId = isset($data['quizId']) ? $data['quizId'] : 0;
        $prefix = !empty($data['prefix']) ? trim($data['prefix']) : '';
        $quizMapper = new WpProQuiz_Model_QuizMapper();

        $quiz = $quizMapper->fetch($quizId);

        $r = $ctn->handleAddInToplist($quiz);

        if ($quiz->isToplistActivated() && $quiz->isToplistDataCaptcha() && get_current_user_id() == 0) {
            $captcha = WpProQuiz_Helper_Captcha::getInstance();

            if ($captcha->isSupported()) {
                $captcha->remove($prefix);
                $captcha->cleanup();

                if ($r !== true) {
                    $r['captcha']['img'] = WPPROQUIZ_CAPTCHA_URL . '/' . $captcha->createImage();
                    $r['captcha']['code'] = $captcha->getPrefix();
                }
            }
        }

        if ($r === true) {
            $r = array('text' => __('You signed up successfully.', 'wp-pro-quiz'), 'clear' => true);
        }

        return json_encode($r);
    }

    public static function ajaxShowFrontToplist($data)
    {
        // workaround ...
        $_POST = $_POST['data'];

        $quizIds = empty($data['quizIds']) ? array() : array_unique((array)$data['quizIds']);
        $toplistMapper = new WpProQuiz_Model_ToplistMapper();
        $quizMapper = new WpProQuiz_Model_QuizMapper();
        $j = array();

        foreach ($quizIds as $quizId) {
            $quiz = $quizMapper->fetch($quizId);
            if ($quiz == null || $quiz->getId() == 0) {
                continue;
            }

            $toplist = $toplistMapper->fetch($quizId, $quiz->getToplistDataShowLimit(), $quiz->getToplistDataSort());

            foreach ($toplist as $tp) {
                $j[$quizId][] = array(
                    'name' => $tp->getName(),
                    'date' => WpProQuiz_Helper_Until::convertTime($tp->getDate(),
                        get_option('wpProQuiz_toplistDataFormat', 'Y/m/d g:i A')),
                    'points' => $tp->getPoints(),
                    'result' => $tp->getResult()
                );
            }
        }

        return json_encode($j);
    }
}
```

and from model WpProQuiz_Model_Toplist.php:

```
<?php

class WpProQuiz_Model_Toplist extends WpProQuiz_Model_Model
{
    protected $_toplistId;
    protected $_quizId;
    protected $_userId;
    protected $_date;
    protected $_name;
    protected $_email;
    protected $_points;
    protected $_result;
    protected $_ip;

    public function setToplistId($_toplistId)
    {
        $this->_toplistId = (int)$_toplistId;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getToplistId()
    {
        return $this->_toplistId;
    }

    public function setQuizId($_quizId)
    {
        $this->_quizId = (int)$_quizId;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getQuizId()
    {
        return $this->_quizId;
    }

    public function setUserId($_userId)
    {
        $this->_userId = (int)$_userId;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->_userId;
    }

    public function setDate($_date)
    {
        $this->_date = (int)$_date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->_date;
    }

    public function setName($_name)
    {
        $this->_name = (string)$_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->_name;
    }

    public function setEmail($_email)
    {
        $this->_email = (string)$_email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->_email;
    }

    public function setPoints($_points)
    {
        $this->_points = (int)$_points;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPoints()
    {
        return $this->_points;
    }

    public function setResult($_result)
    {
        $this->_result = (float)$_result;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getResult()
    {
        return $this->_result;
    }

    public function setIp($_ip)
    {
        $this->_ip = (string)$_ip;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIp()
    {
        return $this->_ip;
    }
}
```

Comment: This plugin seems to use some kind of MVC setup so you're going to want to look in the views rather than the controllers.  That said, you should be careful about editing a plugin directly.